# Refresh Token AWS Cognito User Pool, Code Block Not Even Running

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to refresh a users  tokens, and I am doing this in a "child" app that only has access to idToken, accessToken, refreshToken, and the user's information aside for their password. It is sandboxed and cannot communicate to main app.

I have attempted the following code to run initiateAuth

```
let authParams = [
    "REFRESH_TOKEN": user.refreshToken, 
    "SECRET_HASH": config.getClientSecret()
]

let provider = AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey: config.getClientSecret())

let req = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderInitiateAuthRequest()
req?.authFlow = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAuthFlowType.refreshToken
req?.clientId = config.getClientId()
req?.authParameters = authParams

provider.initiateAuth(req!).continueWith() {
    resp in
    print("I'm not running")
    if (resp != nil) {
        print(resp.error.debugDescription)
    } else {
        print(resp.result.debugDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Shockingly enough, the continueWith block of code doesn't even run at all, and the print statement "I'm not running" is not called. I'm at a loss of what to do, as this seems to be doing what they do in their SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.m#L173

Comment: Have you previously registered a AWSCognitoIdentityProvider object with the clientSecret as the key? i.e, can you confirm provider != nil?

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @behrooziAWS solved this same issue for me.

Specifically, even though the initializer for `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey:)` is documented in XCode's quick help as:

```
+ (nonnull instancetype)CognitoIdentityProviderForKey:(nonnull NSString *)key;
```

it can (and it will) return `nil` if the `CognitoIdentityProvider` for the provided `key` is not found.  One case this happens is when `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.register(with:forKey:)` was never called for the provided `key`.

It's even more confusing when `if(provider != nil)` produces a compiler warning that it will always be `true`.  I had to use the following code snippet to get things working without warnings:

```
    let provider: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider? = AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(
        forKey: config.getClientSecret())
    guard provider != nil else {
        fatalError("AWSCognitoIdentityProvider not registered!")
    }
```

<strike>P.S.  I hope someone with more experience in Swift+ObjC can comment on why the initializer shows up or is translated as `nonnull instancetype` even though the Objective C source code only has `instancetype`.</strike>
Edit:  The reason why this initializer (and pretty much everything else in the `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.h` file) is annotated with `nonnull` automatically is because of the `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` macros.  In the case of `CognitoIdentityProviderForKey`, this non-null assumption should not be valid.